# Monotouch and Mono for Android support satellite assemblies for internationalization

Tags: localization, xamarin.ios, multiplatform

Does Monotouch and Mono for Android supports satellite assemblies for internationalization?

Answer (score 1):

These have been working for a while in MonoTouch, we in fact use this in our game, [Draw a Stickman: EPIC](http://epic.drawastickman.com).

They recently add this to Mono for Android in [4.6.3](http://docs.xamarin.com/releases/android/xamarin.android_4/xamarin.android_4.6.3).